# Highstock data points pixel spacing

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there a way to set point spacing in pixels on x/y axis for highstock? For example data points should be 5px apart.

Also is there way to shift chart left or right? For example shift all data points 5px right or left?

Answer (score 0):

The spacing between points can be control by

- [pointPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.column.groupPadding)
- [groupPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.column.pointPadding)
- [pointWidth](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.column.pointWidth)

Comment: Anything that can be used with line chart (in highstock)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the points of a line to be a certain distance apart, you need to make sure that the width of the plot area, divided by the number of points , equals that pixel value.

(or divided by the number of axis units, if you are artificially setting a min and max beyond the range of the data)

There can't possibly be a property to account for this - it's all about the space available and the number of points.

As for shifting left or right, it depends exactly what you mean. If you're looking to add spacing to the left or right end of the x axis, you can use `midPadding` or `maxPadding`.

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minPadding
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.maxPadding